# Everytime I close firefox the mozilla crach reporter pops up

Tags: firefox

I have just updated to 14.04, and now everytime that I close firefox, either by using the "X" in the top panel or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, the mozilla crash reported pops-up apologizing that firefox crashed and asking me to submit a report.

Anyone else getting this, and more importantly does anyone know how to stop it?

Comment: Not a bug report. A Firefox menu-autohide extension was causing the problem (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable all your Firefox extensions and check if that stops Firefox from crashing. Then enable your extensions one by one until you find the Firefox extension that is causing the problem. Then check the settings for that extension to see if changing the extension's settings can prevent Firefox from crashing. Sometimes you don't to need to remove the extension, just click the Preferences button (*Tools* -> *Add-ons* -> *Extensions* -> click the extension's *Preferences* button) and change the settings.

In addition to the aforementioned, there are some Firefox extensions that have settings that can be accessed through the Firefox menubar (*Tools* -> ...). If you encounter one of these, leave a comment in case anyone else has had a Firefox crashing problem with that extension.

Comment: Thanks - this sorted it. I had an menu-autohide add-on which was causing the reported to pop-up on exit.